# Perforce eclipse plugin: difference between "get latest revision" and "synchronize with depot"

Tags: eclipse-plugin, perforce

I have a question about the Perforce Eclipse plugin, under project(right click)> team, there have "get lastest revision" and "synchronize with depot", what is the difference between the two of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Get latest revision* fetches a newer copy of the file from Perforce, if a newer version is available.

*Synchronize with depot* shows you a preview of anything new from Perforce that you could bring into your project.  It's a useful preview of what *Get latest revision* would actually do.

There's also *Check consistency* which shows you anything modified locally that Perforce doesn't know about, kind of like a *status* command.

I agree that the terms are confusing, but I think these are Eclipse standards to some extent.  *Synchronize with depot* opens up Eclipse's Synchronize view for example.